# "update-database" Command not updating the model in the underlying Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Earlier i have these two classes and i created migration for that and the database table are generated.
but i have to add another property to the Type in a specific order so for that i created an empty migration and using the "sql" method and dropped these two table because of a foreign key contraint.
Now i have made all the changes to the "type" class.
so i am using update-database commmand the EntityFramework not picking these classes ?

Given Classes => "Before Changes".

```
public class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SignUpFee { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to remove the earlier migrations record related to these tables from table "**__MigrationHistory**" and remove the earlier related migration files from Migration folder for future migration run(clarity) and add mapping against those classes LIKE:

```
public class TypeMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Type>
    {
        public TypeMapping()
        {
            // Keys
            HasKey(t => t.ID);

            //Property
            Property(t => t.SignUpFee);
            Property(t => t.Discount);            

            //Table
            ToTable("Type");
        }
    }

public class CustomerMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
        {
            public CustomerMapping()
            {
                // Keys
                HasKey(t => t.ID);

                //Property
                Property(t => t.Name);

                //Table
                ToTable("Customer");
            }
        }
```

Then, run following commands:

1) add-migration "MigrationName"
2) update-database